# Android ViewModelProvider causes application to immediately shut down

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

**SOLVED** - kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version" missing in build.gradle

When i'm adding ViewModelProvider to my code, after opening a fragment in which it's added, my app immediately closes. Below i've provided the whole fragment class and error message. I've tracked the issue, and the application worked perfectly fine, before adding just one line with ViewModelProvider. Any idea why it's happening?

**AddFragment**

```
class AddFragment : Fragment() {

private var _binding: FragmentAddBinding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding!!

private lateinit var mTaskViewModel: TaskViewModel

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    _binding = FragmentAddBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    mTaskViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[TaskViewModel::class.java]

    binding.newTaskButton.setOnClickListener { insertToDatabase() }
}

private fun insertToDatabase() {

}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
}
```

}

**ERROR**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.randoo, PID: 25691
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.randoo.data.TaskViewModel
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:320)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:304)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:278)
    at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.kt:128)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:187)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:153)
    at com.example.randoo.fragments.AddFragment.onViewCreated(AddFragment.kt:33)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3128)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:552)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1890)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1814)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1751)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:538)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:312)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:304) 
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:278) 
    at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.kt:128) 
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:187) 
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:153) 
    at com.example.randoo.fragments.AddFragment.onViewCreated(AddFragment.kt:33) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3128) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:552) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1890) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1814) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1751) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:538) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003) 
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for com.example.randoo.data.TaskDatabase. TaskDatabase_Impl does not exist
    at androidx.room.Room.getGeneratedImplementation(Room.java:100)
    at androidx.room.RoomDatabase$Builder.build(RoomDatabase.java:1486)
    at com.example.randoo.data.TaskDatabase$Companion.getDatabase(TaskDatabase.kt:28)
    at com.example.randoo.data.TaskViewModel.<init>(TaskViewModel.kt:17)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343) 
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:312) 
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:304) 
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:278) 
    at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.kt:128) 
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:187) 
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:153) 
    at com.example.randoo.fragments.AddFragment.onViewCreated(AddFragment.kt:33) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3128) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:552) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1890) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1814) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1751) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:538) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

**TaskDatabase**

```
@Database(entities = [Task::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
```

abstract class TaskDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

```
abstract fun taskDao(): TaskDao

companion object {
    @Volatile
    private var INSTANCE: TaskDatabase? = null

    fun getDatabase(context: Context): TaskDatabase{
        val tempInstance = INSTANCE
        if (tempInstance != null){
            return tempInstance
        }
        synchronized(this){
            val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                context.applicationContext,
                TaskDatabase::class.java,
                "task_database"
            ).build()
            INSTANCE = instance
            return instance
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: If you examine your stack trace, you will see that your problem is in your `TaskDatabase`, not the fragment or the viewmodel.

Comment: nothing seems wrong in my TaskDatabase, but i'll provide it in my question as well